# mounting secret to kubernetes pod with file extension

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I have a secret that I am trying to mount with a .yml extension on its name. Is there a way to do this? I have the following external secret (changed values to dummies):

```
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test-nm
spec:
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: 
    name: 

  refreshInterval: "24h"

  target:
    name: test
    creationPolicy: 'Owner'
    deletionPolicy: "Delete"

  data:
  - secretKey: some_key_name
    remoteRef:
      key: some_key.yml
```

And this is a portion of my deployment file where I add the mount:

```
volumes:
        - name: some-secret
          secret:
            secretName: some_key_name
      containers:
      - name: some_app
        volumeMounts:
          - name: some-secret
            mountPath: /user/secrets/
```

the secret mounts but does not have the .yml at the end. Any ideas will be appreciated thank you!!

Tips, or ideas what I can do to mount secret with .yml extension

Comment: Sorry, where's the `.yml`? In the secret key, value, somewhere else? It doesn't appear anywhere in your examples

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. Asking about a ".yml extension" for a mount like this doesn't make any sense -- when you mount a secret at `/user/secrets`, then keys in that secret will be exposed as files in the filesystem. The names are whatever you've named the keys. If you want a .yml extension, then name the key appropriately.

Comment: Thank you @Phil, where would I add the .yml in the external secrets file?

Comment: Thank you @larsks To make sure I am understanding, would I add the .yml in the ExternalSecret file? More specifically, in this section? data:
  - secretKey: some_key_name
    remoteRef:
      key: some_key

Comment: I edited my post, with the key: some_key.yml. However, the issue persists

Comment: It looks like you've modified the remoteRef, which is the name of the key in your secret store. You probably wanted to modify the value of `secretKey`. Look at the generated Secret resource and see if the keys are named as you expect.